# Configure Sharepoint site to access over the Internet

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, sharepoint-2013

I have a microsoft Azure VM and installed a standalone Sharepoint 2013 server on windows server 2008 R2, I have setup everything and working fine but i am not able to configure site for accessing it over the internet.

i mean can anyone please suggest step by step procedure to configure sharepoint 2013 site that can be accessed over the internet/out of LAN zone like google/Microsoft websites.

Comment: i don understand, when i posted this question, it was assigned -1 automatically, is there anything wrong with the question???

Comment: Well... 1: Not programming-related - it's infrastructure. 2: You're asking for a tutorial recommendation (a step-by-step procedure) - off-topic. 3: You provided no details of your setup other than you telling us everything is set up and working fine. FYI there are many questions asked (and answered) here that address dealing with endpoints (classic VMs) and network security group inbound rules (ARM-based VMs), which allow for inbound traffic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon , 1. Yes it is programming related, you need to do manual URL Mapping whereever you are using it, i accept i couldn't explain it correctly but you would have asked appropriate information you need. 2. I asked Step-by Step info bcoz i wasn't aware of Azure VM Restriction, you would have suggested general setup we have to check.

Comment: @DavidMakogon , 3. in this question neither i am asking how to setup sharepoint nor the other software, i am concerned about how to access sharepoint site over the internet (A Basic Steps that has to be taken care of) find this https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/. however thanks for your reply and time. I have posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the solution for almost 3 days and found what is necessary to access sharepoint 2013 site over the internet.

1. if you are running a standalone system then here is this [LINK](https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/) that'll explain how to setup your environment, that worked for me.
2. if you are running an azure VM, you'll have to check for static IP  and reserved IP for your VM (Suggested by MS Professionals), and create an endpoint for the sharepoint port to give access over the internet, Then you can access your sharepoint site using VM's http:/// or http://.

Hope it helps somebody.